# asp:gridview header vertical alignment using css

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to align my grid view vertically using css but the problem is when I do that the data fields goes under the header fields instead of being parallel to it.

what I need is:

**HEADER1 : DATA FIELD1**

**HEADER2 : DATA FIELD2**

**HEADER3 : DATA FIELD3**

But what I get is:

**HEADER1**

**HEADER2**

**HEADER3**

**DATA FIELD1**

**DATA FIELD2**

**DATA FIELD3**

look at the image for better understanding.

[image]

Please help me fix it.

CSS:

```
.ChildGrid td{
  background-color: #eee !important;
  color: black;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height:200%;
}
.ChildGrid th{
  background-color: #6C6C6C !important;
  color: White;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height:200%;
}
table.ChildGrid, table.ChildGrid tr, table.ChildGrid td, table.ChildGrid th{
  display:block
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSDate2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">

  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="ID">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="நிகழ்ச்சி">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textFunction" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Function") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="நிகழ்ச்சி தேதி">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textFunctionDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FunctionDate") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: try to use `HeaderStyle-CssClass` in gridview and add a css class to make it align in same line

Comment: ok I've added the css class can you please help me with the exact css code to align it with the data field?

Comment: only one row of data?

Comment: yes only one row of data

Comment: if you can paste rendered mark up then it will be easier to answer

Comment: Instead of css you can try it with code

Comment: image attached and no i wanna do it css without backend code if possible please

Comment: css is not the way to proceed here. Try pivoting the table. http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/05/10/pivot-data-in-gridview---a-generic-pivot-method-with.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried something else instead of working on CSS

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSDate2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid" OnRowUpdating="updategvSDate2">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>நிகழ்ச்சி</th>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="textFunction" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Function") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>நிகழ்ச்சி தேதி</th>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="textFunctionDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FunctionDate") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>நிகழ்ச்சி நேரம்</th>
            <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="textFunctionTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FunctionTime") %>'>
               <asp:ListItem Value="">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="காலை 05:00AM - 01:00PM">காலை 05:00AM - 01:00PM</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="மாலை 02:00PM - 10:00PM">மாலை 02:00PM - 10:00PM</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="முழு நாள் 05:00AM - 10:00PM">முழு நாள் 05:00AM - 10:00PM</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

now my table looks like this

[image]

thanks Naveen i got this idea from the link you sent

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong datapresentation control here. What you ideally need is a [`asp:DetailsView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use it like this.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="FunctionDetails" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    HeaderText="Author Details">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="நிகழ்ச்சி">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textFunction" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%#Eval("Function") %>'>
                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="நிகழ்ச்சி தேதி">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textFunctionDate" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%#Eval("FunctionDate") %>'>
                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: ok ill try this method but will i be able to use update button on this one?

Comment: ok but this is a nested gridview which gets the data from the backend code and im afraid it would mess it all up but ill try anyway and see

Comment: You Could use `Repeater control` and set the attribute `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"`. May Help you.